# How to merge code from one Git repo A to Git repo B using Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, automation

I want to merge a code from Git repo A to Git repo B. Basically we do development in git repo A and have all code reviews and merged to main branch of git repo A. Whenever any pull request merges into repo A, I want to push the same code to another repo that is repo B. The purpose of doing this is to ensure both repo A and repo B is always same. Both Repositories belong to the same Organization.

Is this possible at all via WebHooks? if yes, please share me any guidance or document.

Also please share me if there is any other easy way.

Comment: Do both repositories share the same git history?

Comment: yes, I want to maintain the history between 2 repos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the same history in both repos you can simply add a second repo as a `remote` and push the code from A to B. You can read more about working with remotes [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

A `Jenkins` pipeline will look like something below. You can trigger the Pipeline either by a Webhook or a Polling Timer.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Sync Repos') {
            steps {
                sh """
                  git clone -b main git@github.com:ORG/A.git
                  cd A  
                  git remote add B git@github.com:ORG/B.git
                  git push B main
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, I am new to Jenkins. Can you give any reference on how to do above steps ?

Comment: @MarioR Have a look at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/

Comment: Thanks. Do I also need to setup remote repo in Git? Is above syntax correct """?

Comment: @MarioR Above is a working pipeline. `"""` denotes multiline strings. You need git installed in your Jenkins agent for this to work.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Verified that Jenkins have git installed. Do I need to setup any webhooks in repo A to listen ?

Comment: @MarioR triggering part is upto you. For now you can manually execute the Job. But as I mentioned you can either use a Timer or a Webhook to automate the triggering part.